# Re render Header in ReactJs

Tags: react-native, react-router

I have index.js as below code:

```
<relevant imports>

function Header(){
       return(<HeaderComponent/>);
}

ReactDOM.render(
<div>
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/page1" component={page1} />
                <Route path="/page2" component={page2} />
                <Route path="/page3" component={page3} />
                <Route path="/home" component={PortfolioPageComponent} />
                <Route path="/" component={WelcomePage} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </Router>
</div>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
ReactDOM.render(<Header />, document.getElementById('page-header'));
```

now when I am opening my app it goes to `WelcomePage` .In this component  I have authorization logic. once Authetication is done, Page is redirecting to `PortfolioPageComponent` but **header** component is NOT getting reloaded. 
How can I re-render Header component also on each redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the header component OUTSIDE the switch component allows it to render with each route. This way, no matter which route you navigate to, the components outside of the switch will always be rendered. This could be including a header before the switch component and a footer afterwards.

Comment: will it re-render on switch? I want to display some icons on header on the basis of page you are in

Comment: And I want to render it in page-header element only

Comment: You can simply choose what you please for what's rendered outside switch. And no, it will not necessarily rerender automatically. To include icons on the basis of the page you're in, you could use state for the header, and whenever state changes, the component is automatically rerendered by React.

Comment: <BrowserRouter forceRefresh={true}>